# How can I count all deleted elements when I remade the list into a set(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, set, tuples

I need to make a function, which will take a list or tuple and remade it into a set. As there are no duplicate elements in the set, I need to write the number of all deleted elements. This is my code,

```
def find_type(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        arg = set(arg)
        return arg
    elif isinstance(arg, tuple):
        a = list(arg)
        return set(a)


print(find_type((1, 2, 2, 3)))
```

and answer

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

The function works, so i just do not know how to count and write the number of deleted elements

Comment: The total number of deleted elements is `len(original_list) - len(set(original_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following relation:

```
number1 = len(arg)
number2 = len(find_type(arg))
number = number1-number2
```

Answer (score 1):

Number of deleted elements is simply the difference in length of list/tuple and set.

Also, you don't need to check if `arg` is instance of list or tuple (and even if you do, do it in one conditional). `set` accepts all iterable types (like lists, tuples, strings, etc.).